# What are some good open-source iOS projects to study at?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, open-source

I am looking for a good well designed iOS code/framework that is open sourced out there that I can study on. What I mean good design is, they follow good object oriented concepts, code is clean, and organized, possibly has some unit testing in it as well. I wanted to learn these concepts and apply it to my projects as well. Any suggestions are appreciated

Answer (score 11):

Apple provides [some great sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code).

Additionally, I suggest looking at the abundance of iOS code available on code sharing sites such as [GitHub](https://github.com/search?authenticity_token=125f540f7610efd2a53d57407f0483db6d6dd852&type=Everything&language=Objective-C&q=language:%20objective-c&repo=&langOverride=&x=0&y=0&start_value=1). There's some great work done by some StackOverflow members. [Marcus Zarra](https://github.com/mzarra) and [Dave DeLong](https://github.com/davedelong) are two such people. [I've also posted some code](https://github.com/mosheberman) up there as well. Just so you know, a lot of code posted on GitHub are not complete projects, but libraries or useful classes.

There's also [the Three20 framework](http://three20.info/), published by Facebook.

At risk of shameless self plugging, [here's a project](https://github.com/MosheBerman/SpeedDialApp) I wrote that's overly commented and fairly simple. The app is a "speed dial" for iPhone. Set a number, flip a switch and you don't need to jump into the phone app to tap on a number in favorites anymore. One tap dialing right from your home screen. I've got two apps based on this code that are out on the App Store, but this app itself is not.

**Edit:**
Since writing this answer I've got some more project, much more complex than the one linked above. [MBCalendarKit](https://github.com/MosheBerman/MBCalendarKit/) is the one I'm most proud of. Feel free to tear it up.

Comment: I know github, but it's hard to find those codes in git hub that you can study on.. some code have bad designs, some are unfinished, some are buggy, etc

Comment: I second the suggestion of looking through Dave DeLong's repositories. I don't have any use for any math parsing, but it sure looks interesting.

Comment: One issue I had with Apple sample code are they aren't big enough. Maybe I should have made my question clearer that I am looking for quite a larger project/working app

Answer (score 4):

I think Apple makes good code [sample codes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code).

Answer (score 0):

three20

http://three20.info/

Put together by facebook.